# Python windows key logger implementation without external libraries

Tags: python, logging, keyboard

All solutions for windows python key loggers depend on pyHook as additional library. Is it possible to write a simple key logger without any external libraries (except win32api)? I searched the web for any solutions however all seem to depend on pyHook. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The [keyboard module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/) can do that and it's pure python, so yes it's possible. But probably a lot of work.

Comment: You just made my day ; ) Thanks! If you would make an answer out of it, I will accept it. I think this will be useful for most people that are in this situation (either wanting to build their own keyboard macros in python like me or writing a keylogger).

Comment: And it was easy to install (pure python and python 3 compatible) not as hard as pyHook!